# Is this correct in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I was wondering if below is correct, I have tested it is working, I just want an opinion.

file a.php:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass {

    public function ShowMessage($s) {
        echo $s;
    }

}
```

file b.php

```
require_once 'a.php';

use MyNamespace\MyClass as MyAlias;

$class = new MyAlias;
$class->ShowMessage('Hello World!');

/* I have same results if I use this */
$class2 = new MyNamespace\MyClass();
$class2->ShowMessage('Hello World!');
```

Thank you.

Comment: If it works for you then it is correct.

Comment: Which part are you not sure of? You need to ask a specific question, not just a general opinion.

Comment: I just want to know if those are both correct if I will use it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be correct? The whole point of the `as` clause is to allow you to give a short name to a class, and then use that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your code looks correct. I would usually do that. Are you still learning PHP or you like to do your own classes? If you are then it is correct, but if not i recommend you try using a framework is this is going to become a website or something like that

[Try this](http://www.codeigniter.com)

Its code igniter. It does not need Composer to run. It has many libraries with the download files. Its a MVC structure Framework, so the logic goes there and is pretty simple to use i think

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome! i am glad to help